# How to change verbosity of uvm components after certain condition

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am trying to change the UVM verbosity of the simulation after satisfying certain conditions. Verbosity options of different components are passing through the command line as +uvm_set_verbosity. Once the conditions are satisfied, then the simulations should run with the the command line +uvm_set_verbosity option. Till then simulation runs with low verbosity for all components.

Looking through the UVM library code, it appears that there is a function called m_set_cl_msg_args(). This function calls three other functions that appear to consume the command line arguments like: +uvm_set_verbosity, +uvm_set_action, +uvm_set_severity.

So what I did was get the uvm_root instance from the uvm_coreservice singleton, and then use the get_children() function from uvm_component class to recursively get a queue of all of the uvm_components in the simulation. Then call the m_set_cl_msg_args() function on all of the components.

My code looks like:

```
    begin
     uvm_root r;
     uvm_coreservice_t cs_t;
     uvm_component array_uvm[$];
     cs_t = uvm_coreservice_t::get();
     r = cs_t.get_root();

     r.get_children(array_uvm);
     foreach(array_uvm[i])
       array_uvm[i].m_set_cl_msg_args();
    end
```

Even though this code compiles properly, But this is not changing verbosity. Any idea ?
Moreover I am able to print all the components in array_uvm. So I am guessing
array_uvm[i].m_set_cl_msg_args();
this as a wrong call.

Anyone have any other suggestion to change verbosity during run time.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use functions in the UVM that are not documented in the language reference manual. They can (and do) change in any revision. I'm guessing +uvm_set_verbosity only works at time 0 by default.

There is already a [function](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.1b/html/files/base/uvm_component-svh.html#uvm_component.set_report_verbosity_level_hier) to do what you want

```
umm_top.set_report_verbosity_level_hier()
```

I suggest using `+UVM_VERBOSITY=UVM_LOW` to start your test, and then define your own switch for activating the conditional setting.

If you want a specific component, use `component_h.set_report_verbosity_level()` (add the `_hier` to set all its children)

You can use the UVM's command line processor `get_arg_values()` method to specify the name of the component(s) you want to set, and then use umm_top.find() to get a handle to the component.

Comment: This one I tried.. But here the issue is all the components in the hierarchy will change their verbosity accordingly to the parameter we are passing. Is there any way to do this for some particular components and that too through command line

Comment: Updated answer with a suggested way of getting specific components.